# Flask-SocketIo always using Polling

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask, vercel, flask-socketio

I have made an web app with **flask** and implemented **socket-io** in it using `Flask-SocketIO` but it is continuously using **Polling** method instead of **Web Sockets**.

My `JS` file:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    socket = io.connect(document.location.protocol + '//' + document.domain, {rememberTransport: false});

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('Websocket connected!');
    });

    socket.on('status', function(data) {
        console.log("HIIIIII");
    });
});
```

And my `app.py` file:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)

# My all other functions

@socketio.on('connect')
def connect_handler():
    print("f")

@socketio.on('status')
def status(message):
    emit('status', {'msg': session.get('name') + ' has entered the room.'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    socketio.init_app(app)
    socketio.run(app)
```

And my Chrome Console is generating the following polling error:

```
GET https://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O2ylx6M 404
```

**It is hosted on vercel.**

Comment: have you misspelt 'status' as 'staus' in the decorator for `def status`?

Comment: no sorry it's correct in codes by mistake in pasting here it was written wrong.

Comment: What is the problem? That the client is using polling? That is normal. Socket.IO connections start with polling, and then it is upgraded to WebSocket.